# Find the cubic equation of roots $α, β, γ$.

Tags: polynomials, roots, cubics

Taken from Fitzpatrick $4$ unit course textbook. The question says:

If the cubic equation $\ ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$ has roots $α, β, γ$. Find the cubic equation who's roots are $α^2, β^2, γ^2$

I keep getting a $±$ sign that I can't get rid of. The answer in the back is $x(ax+c)^2=(bx+d)^2$

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that if $$x^3 + \frac{b}{a} x^2 + \frac{c}{a}x + \frac{d}{a} = (x-\alpha)(x-\beta)(x-\gamma),$$ then 
$$
x^3 + \frac{b}{a} x^2 + \frac{c}{a}x + \frac{d}{a} = x^3 - (\alpha + \beta + \gamma) x^2 + (\alpha \beta + \alpha \gamma + \beta \gamma) x - (\alpha \beta \gamma).
$$
Therefore
\begin{align*}
\alpha \beta \gamma &= -\frac{d}{a}\\
\alpha \beta + \alpha \gamma + \beta \gamma &= \;\;\frac{c}{a}\\
\alpha + \beta + \gamma &= - \frac{b}{a}.
\end{align*}

Now the polynomial we would like to find is $(x - \alpha^2)(x - \beta^2)(x - \gamma^2).$ Expanding this out we see this is equal to 
$$
x^3 - (\alpha^2 + \beta^2 + \gamma^2)x^2 + (\alpha^2 \beta^2 + \alpha^2 \gamma^2 + \beta^2 \gamma^2) x - (\alpha^2 \beta^2 \gamma^2).
$$
To find these expressions in terms of $a,b,c,$ and $d$, we just fiddle with the above three equations.

The easiest value to find is $\alpha^2 \beta^2 \gamma^2$. Clearly this is just $d^2/a^2$. To find $\alpha^2 + \beta^2 + \gamma^2$, observe that 
$$
(\alpha + \beta + \gamma)^2 = (\alpha^2 + \beta^2 + \gamma^2) + 2(\alpha \beta + \alpha \gamma + \beta \gamma).
$$
Therefore 
$$
\alpha^2 + \beta^2 + \gamma^2 = \frac{b^2}{a^2} - 2 \frac{c}{a}.
$$
Finally, to calculate $\alpha^2 \beta^2 + \alpha^2 \gamma^2 + \beta^2 \gamma^2$, we observe that 
$$
(\alpha \beta + \alpha \gamma + \alpha \beta)^2 = (\alpha^2 \beta^2+\alpha^2 \gamma^2 + \beta^2 \gamma^2) + 2(\alpha \beta \gamma)(\alpha + \beta + \gamma)
$$
so the value in question is equal to 
$$
\frac{c^2-2bd}{a^2}.
$$

Putting this altogether, the polynomial we are looking for must be
$$
x^3 - \left(\frac{b^2 - 2ac}{a^2}\right)x^2 + \left(\frac{c^2-2bd}{a^2}\right) x - \frac{d^2}{a^2}.
$$
This polynomial will have the same zeros if we multiply by a constant, so we multiply by $a^2$ to get the polynomial
\begin{align*}
x^3 - (b^2 - 2ac) x^2 + (c^2 - 2bd)x - d^2 &= (x^3 + 2ac x^2 + c^2x) - (b^2x^2 + 2bd x + d^2) \\
&= x(ax+c)^2 - (bx+d)^2,
\end{align*}
as desired.

Answer (score 3):

Take the equation $$ax^3+bx^2+cx+d=0$$ which has solutions $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$. Group the odd and even powers on each side and factor to obtain $$x(ax^2+c) = -(bx^2+d).$$
Now squaring both sides gives
$$x^2(ax^2+c)^2 = (bx^2+d)^2.$$
This equation has solutions $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$ but only contains even powers of $x$ so we can make the substitution $y=x^2$ to obtain the equation $$y(ay+c)^2 = (by+d)^2$$
which has solutions $\alpha^2$, $\beta^2$, $\gamma^2$. You can replace $y$ by $x$ to obtain the answer in the back.

Comment: This is especially nice!

Answer (score 1):

Let $x^2=y$

We have $ax^3+bx^2+cx+d=0\ \ \ \ (1)$

$(1)\implies y(ax+b)=-cx-d\iff x=-\dfrac{by+d}{ay+c}$

Ste this value of $x$ in $(1)$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** We can write the given cubic polynomial as
$$ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d = a(x - \alpha) (x - \beta) (x - \gamma).$$
Expanding the r.h.s. and comparing like terms gives
\begin{align}
b &= -a(\alpha + \beta + \gamma) \\
  &\,\,\vdots
\end{align}
(These are essentially [Vieta's Formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta's_formulas).)

> **Additional hint** Similarly, the cubic polynomial $A X^3 + B X^2 + C X + D$ whose roots are $\alpha^2, \beta^2, \gamma^2$ can be written as $$A X^3 + B X^2 + C X + D = (x - \alpha^2) (x - \beta^2) (x - \gamma^2),$$ and again expanding the r.h.s. gives, e.g., \begin{align} B &= -(\alpha^2 + \beta^2 + \gamma^2) \\ &\,\,\vdots \end{align} (Of course, this polynomial is only determined up to multiplication by a nonzero constant, which in particular does not change the roots. The choice of $1$ for the leading coefficient above simplifies some computations.) 
>  All that remains now is to write the coefficients $B, C, D$ in terms of the coefficients $a, b, c, d$. The two applications of Vieta's Formulas above expressions all of these coefficients in terms of symmetric functions of the roots $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$, so the coefficients can be related in terms of [Newton's Identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities), which give, e.g., $$\alpha^2 + \beta^2 + \gamma^2 = (\alpha + \beta + \gamma)^2 - 2(\beta \gamma + \gamma \alpha + \alpha \beta).$$ Rearranging earlier equations and substituting give e.g., $$-B = \left(-\frac{b}{a}\right)^2 - 2 \left(\frac{c}{a}\right),$$ or $$B = \frac{2 a c - b^2}{a^2}.$$

Comment: Why isnt Newton's Identities hidden in the spoiler?

Comment: The link you mean? It looks hidden to me, perhaps this is a browser HTML interpretation issue? (I'm using Chrome 43.)

Comment: Yup, I am using the latest version of Chrome: Version 43.0.2357.130 m. The link is not hidden.

Comment: Very strange, though I suppose besides aesthetics it doesn't do any harm.

Comment: ^True that. However, I'll look more into it, because I find it interesting.

Comment: I only know a little about them, but symmetric polynomials are a deep and powerful subject.

Answer (score 0):

$$ax^3+bx^2+cx+d=a^3(x-\alpha)(x-\beta)(x-\gamma)$$

Set $x=y$ to get $$ay^3+by^2+cy+d=a^3(y-\alpha)(y-\beta)(y-\gamma)\ \ \ \  (1)$$

Set $x=-y$ to get $$a(-y)^3+b(-y)^2+c(-y)+d=a^3(-y-\alpha)(-y-\beta)(-y-\gamma)$$

$$\iff ay^3-by^2+cy-d=a^3(y+\alpha)(y+\beta)(y+\gamma)\ \ \ \ (2)$$

Multiply $(1),(2)$ to get $$a^6(y^2-\alpha^2)(y^2-\beta^2)(y^2-\gamma^2)=(ay^3+cy)^2-(by^2+d)^2$$

Set $y^2=u$